# Decimal to Binary Converter in C++

Tags: c++, binary, integer, decimal

My task is to create a simple decimal to binary converter without using any strings or arrays.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int64_t n;
  int64_t i = 1;
  int64_t bit;
  int64_t fbit;
  
  std::cout << "Number: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> n;
    while (n != 0) {
    bit = n % 2;
    n = n / 2;
    fbit = fbit + (bit * i);
    i = i * 10;

    }
  std::cout << fbit;
  return 0;
}
```

For little numbers this works just perfectly, however large numbers seem to fail. For example: 432471278 doesn't work even though this number is 'just' 29 Bits large. I thought by using 'int64_t' this should work though.

Comment: You turn an n-bit number with value under `2^n`, into n-decimal-digits number with value on the order of `10^n`. This easily overflows.

Comment: Also, `fullbit` is an undeclared identifier; this code wouldn't compile.

Comment: so what would you do?

Comment: `int64_t fbit;` was not initialized to any value but used in this line: `fbit = fbit + (bit * i);` This is undefined behavior. Remember that local variables are not set to 0 by the language.

Comment: You understand that the 'decimal' vs 'binary' representation is only about display, right? In memory it is stored in 'hex' format and only appears otherwise when printed out with a specific radix.

Comment: @MikelF — “hex” is also about display (base 16). Values are stored in hardware.

Answer (score 2):

`11001110001101111110011101110`, which is binary representation of `432471278`, is 29-digit long and it is too large for `int64_t` when seen as decimal value. (the maximum is `9223372036854775807`, which is 19-digit long)

Also it is bad to use the value of uninitialized non-static local variable `fbit`.

One simple approach is using recursion to have the stack record converted digits until conversion of upper digits are  done.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void convert(int64_t n) {
  if (n > 1) convert(n / 2);
  std::cout << (n % 2);
}

int main() {
  int64_t n;
  
  std::cout << "Number: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> n;
  convert(n);
  std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```